# Lenskit error: recommender has no item recommender

Tags: java, lenskit

I am trying to use Lenskit with the ml-100k/u.data dataset and I want to generate Top-N recommendations for the users. From the lenskit folder, I am executing:

```
/bin/bash  build/install/lenskit/bin/lenskit recommend 42 -n 5 --csv-file=data/ml-100k/u.data
```

And I get the following output when executing the code:

```
INFO  14:58:03.934 [main] org.lenskit.cli.Main Starting LensKit 3.0-SNAPSHOT on Java 1.8.0_40 from Oracle Corporation
INFO  14:58:03.982 [main] org.lenskit.cli.Main Have 4 processors and heap limit of 2626 MiB
INFO  14:58:03.983 [main] o.l.c.u.RecommenderLoader creating fresh recommender
INFO  14:58:06.473 [main] o.l.c.u.RecommenderLoader built recommender in 2.485 s
ERROR 14:58:09.253 [main] o.l.c.commands.Recommend recommender has no item recommender
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no item recommender
        at org.lenskit.cli.commands.Recommend.execute(Recommend.java:90)
        at org.lenskit.cli.Main.main(Main.java:73)
```

I understand I am most likely missing the "Scoring Items", but I am not able to figure out how to compute these. I am completely new with the programme, so any help or advise is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just for clarity: I tried the HelloLenskit package and made the example work. However, there comes the main difference I don't understand. In the HelloLenskit example there is an executable that is run in the build folder and includes the item-item model. 

However, for the normal lenskit package, the executable in the build folder (lenskit) doesn't seem to contain the item-item model information, and I really cannot understand how to make it work...

Comment: Could you include your algorithm configuration? This error usually means that the configuration is not capable of providing an `ItemRecommender`.